# Python - How to improve speed of transformation of string to float

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, numpy

i'm working with a very large dataframe with several types of data.
There are two types of data with some characteristics that i'm interested in transforming efficiently to float

1. String variables with some set of characters that can be mapped to 1, other characters to 0, and the rest to nan
2. String variables that have float numbers in the format '12,34', the function float does not convert them properly because they have commas instead of points, so they need to be replaced first

Currently im doing this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'var1':['Error', 'No Data', 'START', 'OFF'],
                        'var2':['2,65', '3,45', '4', '6,7089'],
                        'var3':['START', 'OFF', 'NON', 'Error']})

statusZero= ['STOP', 'OFF']
statusOne= ['START', 'ON']
statusNaN= ['Error', 'No Data'] # it can be everything else really

patternZero = '|'.join(statusZero)
patternOne = '|'.join(statusOne)
patternNaN = '|'.join(statusNaN)

def to_float(x):
    import re
    try:
        x = x.replace(',', '.')
        x = re.sub(patternZero, '0', x)
        x = re.sub(patternNaN, 'nan', x)
        x = re.sub(patternOne, '1', x)
        return float(x)
    except:
        try:
            return float(x)
        except:
            return np.nan

dataset = dataset.applymap(to_float)
dataset
```

Is there anything i can replace to do this more efficiently and elegant?

Comment: I think you can delete the second try-except entirely and have only `except: return np.nan`.

Answer (score 0):

`.applymap` is a loop over every individual value so it will be very slow. In this case the better alternative is to use `.map` to map your words to 1/0, and use `pd.to_numeric` to deal with any numeric-like numbers (after first replacing the comma with a decimal). Anything not mapped or coverted is `NaN` by default so no need to specify that.

Though these still use `apply`, it's a loop over the columns so these are generally very fast.

```
# Create a dict of your exact replacement to 1/0
d = {'STOP': 0, 'OFF': 0, 'START': 1, 'ON': 1}

df1 = dataset.replace(',', '.', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

for col in dataset.columns:
    dataset[col] = dataset[col].map(d)
    
dataset = dataset.combine_first(df1)
#   var1    var2  var3
#0   NaN  2.6500   1.0
#1   NaN  3.4500   0.0
#2   1.0  4.0000   NaN
#3   0.0  6.7089   NaN
```

---

If you need partial-string matches or case-insensitive matches to map to 1/0 there are ways to do that with the string methods, but there will be some slow-down as the string methods tend to be slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

datadict = {
'var1':['Error', 'No Data', 'START', 'OFF'],
'var2':['2,65', '3,45', '4', '6,7089'],
'var3':['START', 'OFF', 'NON', 'Error']}

statusdict = {
'0':['STOP', 'OFF'],
'1':['START', 'ON'],
'nan':['Error', 'No Data']
}


for datakey in datadict.keys():
    temp = " @ ".join(datadict[datakey]).replace(",",".")
    datadict[datakey] = temp
    for statkey in statusdict.keys():
        for statval in statusdict[statkey]:
            if statval in temp:
                datadict[datakey] = re.sub(statval,statkey,datadict[datakey])

    datadict[datakey] = datadict[datakey].split(" @ ")

print (datadict)

#Load the datadict in your panda df
```

This will be pretty fast as it is **only** using regex when necessary. Plus, it is only iterating the minimum.

So for each var1, var2, var3, you take the list of words.

You make a string with it, choosing a delimiter you won't find elsewhere, you replace your comma.

Then you browse yoru statusdict to just check if one value in the list from the status key is found in the string, if so you re.sub, you split back, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, avoiding apply:

```
import numpy as np

replacements = {v: e for e, vs in zip(['0', 'nan', '1'], [statusZero, statusOne, statusNaN]) for v in vs}
res = dataset.replace(replacements).replace(',', '.', regex=True)
dataset[:] = np.genfromtxt(res.values.flatten()).reshape(res.shape)
print(dataset)
```

**Output**

```
   var1    var2  var3
0   1.0  2.6500   NaN
1   1.0  3.4500   0.0
2   NaN  4.0000   NaN
3   0.0  6.7089   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary instead of regular expressions.  That would make it both faster and simpler:

```
mapping = { 'STOP':0.0,  'OFF':0.0, 'START':1.0, 'ON':1.0 }

def to_float(x):
    try:    return mapping.get(x,float(x.replace(",",".")))
    except: return np.nan
```

If your non-numeric values are within a limited set, you could dynamically augment your mapping dictionary to avoid going through the float conversion process and hitting exceptions repeatedly:

```
def to_float(x):
    try: 
        return mapping.get(x,float(x.replace(",",".")))
    except:
        mapping[x] = np.nan
        return np.nan
```